# Integração de site PHP/MySQL com App Phonegap

Tags: javascript, php, mobile, apache-cordova

Estou criando um site e um App com o Phonegap, sou novo em programar para plataformas mobile.

Esse site tem um banco de dados e quero que este banco de dados esteja disponível diretamente no App, mas não quero acesso remotamento no banco de dados.

Como posso fazer para enviar uma requisição para o PHP do site, e ele me retornar um resultado para ser apresentado no App usando JS? Tem como fazer um "cache" do BD no App, fazer uma cópia diariamente, ou quando houver atualização no BD?

Comment: Esta pergunta é interessante, pois trata de criação de APIs, trafego e troca de dados entre domínios diferentes (cross-domain), utilizacao de jsonp e possivelmente localstorage ou indexdb/websql (para o "cache" das respostas do banco), é bastante coisa, mas o assunto é pertinente.

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro terá de escolher um banco de dados local no PhoneGap, onde o MySQL não está disponível. Talvez o SQLLite... Depois via AJAX fazer uma requisição para um WebService configurado no lado servidor (onde está o MySQL) para trazer o conteúdo do banco central e atualizar o local. Esse WebService pode ser criado em PHP ou qualquer outra linguagem.

Como mencionado, dependendo to tamanho do banco de dados isso pode não ser viável, seja por gerar um tráfego muito grande ou pela rotina de sincronização consumir recursos demais do dispositivo.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo uma forma que eu encontrei para isso é através de webservices. Sobre a questão de fazer uma cópia do bd é possível, só precisa ver se é realmente viável visto que a aplicação com phonegap sofre com problemas de lentidão tornando a utilização pro usuário final um pouco tediosa.